# Standardized library / datatype for general ordinals in Haskell

Tags: haskell, integer, ordinal, ordinals

I am looking to implement a "general" ordinal type that supports multiple "infinities" (e.g. [1,2,..., W, W+1, W+2, .. , 2 W, .., WW, etc]). I was thinking of implementing as a composite number (e.g. [5:4:2578] < [1:5:4:2578] < [1:5:4:2579] < [1:5:5:2]) with Ints, where comparison starts from the end of the list.

Currently i have implemented it as:

```
newtype Ordinal = Order [Int] 
    deriving (Eq)

instance Ord Ordinal where
    (<=) x@(Order xl) y@(Order yl)
        | null xl && null yl = x == y
        | null xl = (Order [0]) <= y
        | null yl = x <= (Order [0])
        | last xl /= last yl = last xl <= last yl
        | otherwise = (init xl) <= (init yl)
```

I feel like my code is not clean / elegant enough. Is there a standardized library / datatype that already does this? Can i refactor my code more?

Comment: This will give the wrong output when the lists have different lengths. Try  `Order [2] <= Order [1, 1]`

Comment: I guess that `[a0,a1,a2,...]` stands for `a0 + W*a1 + W^2*a2 + ...` ? If so, you can proceed by recursion on the first argument: `compare (x:xs) (y:ys)` seems to be computable from `compare xs ys`. I think that defining `compare` is easier here than defining `<=` since you get more information from the recursive call. If `compare xs ys` is LT or GT then `x` and `y` are irrelevant, otherwise (EQ case) they have to be compared.

Comment: hmm, right i did indeed think i should be using compare, i at least do want to do a recursive call. Although i want [a0, a1, a2, .. ] to stand for ... + W^2 * a2 + W * a1 + a0. i currently have rewritten it with compare, except this still does not do what i want.. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, you have a logical error as pointed out by @4castle.  In short, you should only be comparing most significant digits if they are of the *same* significance.  For instance, `[1,2]` is clearly greater than `[3]` even though the last element of `[3]` is greater than the last element of `[1,2]` because the `2` is of greater significance than the `3`.  You may find that `length` is useful here.

One elegant strategy is to do a preliminary check for whether one of your `Ordinal`s is clearly bigger than the other (that is, has digits with higher significance, or is "structurally bigger"), and only continue with the recursive underlying numerical check if not.  As such, consider defining the recursive part as a helper function; and since it's a helper function anyway, you can call it with the `reverse` of the ordinal lists, allowing you to do simple pattern matching on the lists, comparing the most significant digit first, without needing "ugly" functions like `last` and `init`.

Answer (score 1):

For who cares, i settled on the following implementation (helped by the Haskell reddit, in particular the user xplaticus):

```
compare x@(Order xl) y@(Order yl) = compare (length xl',xl') (length yl',yl')
  where
     xl' = dropWhile (0==) xl
     yl' = dropWhile (0==) yl
```

His explanation was similar to DDub's thus i gave DDub the solved check here.